# Formatting dates with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql

I'm trying to do the following Facebook Query Language query:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE app_id = 131580206909839 AND xid = 'daily_thred_production' AND created_time > 2011-03-06 AND created_time < 2011-03-08)
```

The problem is that the dates aren't being recognized and I can't find any documentation on how to format FQL dates from the Facebook developer section. Any thoughts?

*EDIT*
I'm doing all of this from the URL with no programming language. I'm just trying to pull one-off statistics for some co-workers.

Epoch time seems to work, thanks! Only problem is that it's only displaying new users that contributed to the stream for the first time. Unfortunately I'm trying to find everyone in the stream, I'll have to look at the stream table more carefully.

Thanks Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're epoch time (Number of seconds since 00:00:00 Jan 1, 1970 UTC)

You need to convert your dates to epoch time in whatever language you're using.

**EDIT:** If you need an example, let me know what programming lang you're using.